# Received an email saying "A decision has been made on your UK Visa application". What does it mean?

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for a UK visa for work 3 weeks ago and received an email (see below) saying that a decision has been made. But I don't know what exactly it means. I called them and they say that they can't retrieve the result. My friend who got her visa approved said that her email didn't look like this. So I was wondering whether this foreshadows an unsuccessful application?

> Dear XXXXX
>
> Regarding Visa Application: GWFXXXXXX
>
> For: XXXXX
>
> A decision has been made on your UK Visa application.
>
> If you applied via a US Dept. of Homeland Security Application Support Centre or a VFS Premium Application Centre and chose to have your passport mailed back to you directly, that will take place shortly.
>
> If you submitted your application via a VFS Premium Application Centre and chose to collect your passport in person at the end of the process, they will be in contact with you to provide further guidance.
>
> If anyone contacts you advising that your application is still under consideration or that they can influence the outcome of your application in any way, they cannot - please report any such approach to VisaSheffield@homeoffice.gov.uk.
>
> You should not expect to receive any further emails from this office.
>
> Regards
>
> Sheffield Visa Section
>
> This is an automated message - please do not respond to this email address as incoming mail is not answered. UKVI contact details can be found at www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-outside-uk
>
> This email is intended for the addressee(s) only.  All messages sent and received by the Foreign & Commonwealth Office may be monitored in line with relevant UK legislation 
>   available at https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/foreign-commonwealth-office/about/personal-information-charter

Comment: They have decided on your application. There is no hidden meaning.